# In a belongs_to has_many relationship in Rails, how does the 'singlular' side access records from the 'many' side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

It was my understanding that all keys are stored on the 'many' side, ie: if a user has many posts, and posts belong to only one user, foreign keys associating which user "owns" which which post exist only in the post object.

Yet, in my users controller, I can still create a user show page which lists all posts by looping through 'user.posts'.

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: one caveat, I'm using MongoDB / Mongoid, not sure how this pans out with Active Record.

Answer (score 0):

The model with `belongs_to` part holds the column for reference, `user_id` in your situation.

The model with `has_many` part queries the table, where `belongs_to` is, to get all references models.

Hope it helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @maximgladkov. How does this work exactly -- if I view the user object in GenghisApp there are no fields that show an association between user and posts.

Comment: What do you mean by GenghisApp?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's a MongoDB admin app (http://genghisapp.com/). Equivalent statement would be: if you go into the rails console and look at each user object, you won't see post IDs: '#<User _id: 52fb06a7746f6b235a000000, email: "lorin@gmail.com", name: "Lorin", password_salt: "$2a$10$jEdsFwvaCN7UBbEtKi3NL.", password_hash: "$2a$10$jEdsFwvaCN7UBbEtKi3NL.Z6dT538a9C9Y.4fqW8rRQOt4OUXhHqW">'

Comment: Of course, because `Post` model should store a reference in your situation. Check the output of the `Post` object.

Comment: Right, so I'm wondering how I can still access 'user.posts.each' in my users controller. It's a minor point, but I'm curious :)

Comment: It should work right from the box, if `has_many :posts` is specified in `User` model.